# failed to install db-mysql in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have this erreur whene i use this commande : npm install db-mysql
i use windows 7
sameone help me

C:\Users\Mouad>npm install db-mysql
npm http GET http:// registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql
npm http 304 http:// registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql

> db-mysql@0.7.6 install C:\Users\Mouad\node_modules\db-mysql
>   node-waf configure build

'node-waf' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

> db-mysql@0.7.6 preuninstall C:\Users\Mouad\node_modules\db-mysql
>   rm -rf build/*

'rm' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
npm WARN continuing anyway db-mysql@0.7.6 preuninstall: `rm -rf build/*`
npm WARN continuing anyway `cmd "/c" "rm -rf build/*"` failed with 1
npm ERR! db-mysql@0.7.6 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the db-mysql@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the db-mysql package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls db-mysql
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "db-mysql"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Mouad
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mouad\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

thanx :)